# Importing timestamps into Excel

Tags: excel, timestamp, format

I have a text file of a transcription that I am looking to bring into Excel to modify.

The format of the text file is something like this

```
00:01 Speaker  This is a test of the transcription

00:02 Speaker  Thank you for listening
```

The time stamp is in the format `mm:ss`.
I can import easily through cut and paste, but when I try to manipulate column A with the time, Excel assumes the format is `hh:mm`. Even if I format the column before import as `mm:ss`, it imports as

```
01:00 Speaker  This is a test of the transcription

02:00 Speaker  Thank you for listening
```

Hope this makes sense - is there a correct way of importing this text file so the timestamp matches in Excel?

Comment: Have you tried importing from Data tab?  `Data > From Text/CSV`

Comment: If this is an adhoc process you can just divide by 60 to get back to the right format if a more formal import process doesn't do the trick

Comment: thanks I tried data import - same issue.  The divide by 60 looks to be the best option